# Average number of days since a date in postgresql/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date, average

I want to calculate the average number of days since 'date_from' (it varies)

```
User.all.average('? - date_from', Time.now.to_date)
```

Gives the error

```
undefined method `except' for Thu, 27 Nov 2014:Date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations)

The second parameter of `average` is **options**(an hash)

> The options can be used to customize the query with :conditions, :order, :group, :having and :joins.

So you should generate average expression like this:

```
User.average("'#{Time.now.to_date}' - date_from" )
```

Then Rails will generate SQL like this:

```
SELECT AVG('2014-11-27' - date_from) AS avg_id FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#get difference fro all users from Time.now and date_from    
dates = User.all.pluck(:date_from).map{|date| Time.now - date}
#sum all elements from array and divide with number of elements
#to get average 
days = dates.reduce(0,:+)/dates.length
#round to 2 decimal places for better display
days = days.round(2)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but not as elegant as the others.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Date`'s `::today` method, instead of `Time`'s `::now`:

```
User.all.average('? - date_from', Date.today)
```